# android imageview(URL image) in dialog

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
package com.AndroidCustomDialog;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidCustomDialog extends Activity {

static final int CUSTOM_DIALOG_ID = 0;
private String imageFileURL = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=s:cEAELFJHHHKUju9uuXUc&chco=76A4FB&chls=2.0,0.0,0.0&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:%7C0%7C1%7C2%7C3%7C4%7C5%7C1:%7C0%7C50%7C100&chs=200x125&chg=20,50";

TextView customDialog_TextView;
EditText customDialog_EditText;
ImageView myImageView;
Button customDialog_Update, customDialog_Dismiss;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01main);
       button1main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(AndroidCustomDialog.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customlayout);
            dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            text.setText("HIHI JORDAN");
            ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

            try {
                   URL url = new URL(imageFileURL);
                   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();                   
                   HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
                   httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                   httpConn.connect();               
                   if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();                     
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    inputStream.close();
                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                   }
                  } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e1.printStackTrace();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }

            //img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();                   
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
        }

       });       
   }  
}
```

If the imageview just show R.drawable.ic_launcher, it is ok. However, if I want to display the image by URL, there is no image displayed.
What wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you hit the url in IE or some where validated it that you are getting image? it seems your image url is https, but you are using only HTTPURLConnection, shouldn't this be HTTPSURLConnection?

Comment: use `http://chart...` as `imageFileURL` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then I'd recommend that you start checking LogCat before posting here, because it would have told you very clearly that you were attempting to use a feature you hadn't been grated access to.

Answer (score 1):

the main problem is that I forgot to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked LogCat to see if there was any exception thrown when you tried to download the image? Also, what version of Android are you targetting this example for?  If you're targetting 3.X.X or higher (ICS), then I would be almost certain that LogCat will show that the system quietly threw a NetworkOnMainThreadException because you're attempting to download an image from the UI Thread, which starting in Honeycomb is no longer legal.  It doesn't kill your app, but it also doesn't go out and download your image.  In newer versions of Android, network access needs to be moved to a worker thread so that network accesses don't block your main thread.  As such you'd need to use an AsyncTask.  An article describing what I'm talking about can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

If that's not the case, can you post any exceptions that were thrown in LogCat?